# Problems with Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom-editor, slideshow

I have problems with creating a slider. I use the same code as here W3Schools Tryit Editor but something goes wrong all the time. My pics are missing as you can see on example in attachment.

I tried to change src path, but my pics are simply missing all the time. I really don't know what's the reason for that.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Baska Web</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="House.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="Vienna.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="TrainStation.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>






</body>
</html>


**CSS**

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

**JAVA**

let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}



type here
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr8TR.jpg)

Comment: Are the picture files in the same folder as the HTML file? If so, then open dev tools in your browser, go to Network panel, refresh the page and see if it's downloading them or if they are returning 404 errors. Also, try the console panel if there are any errors. I see you wrote "JAVA" instead of Javascript, that gives me the impression that you don't know general webdev concepts, in that case try to follow some tutorials. This is a very subjective opinion, but I don't like w3schools at all, watch some youtube channels like fireship, webdev simplified, kevin powell for css, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Your code works fine - I checked it with CodePen. Only the path to your images is wrong. Insert this image URL to test it yourself: `https://picsum.photos/200/300`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to do what you suggested and there's no 404 errors. I can see 2 of 3 pictures clearly, instead of one picture there is a path.

Comment: Luckyfella I tried and unfortunately it's not working

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/09ancxkd/) is a fiddle example of your code with what Luckyfella suggested. If you're not seeing the images, and there's no 404 in the network tab of your developer tools, try opening it with a different browser (if you can help it, don't use Internet Explorer).

Comment: @FiddlingAway I saw on your example that slideshow is working, however I'm having problems with it. I copy paste exact code in my atom project and I have the same result as before. Maybe it's something simple?

Comment: Does your problem persist when you use Google Chrome, Firefox, or MS Edge to view your page? Maybe it's something related to Internet Explorer. If it's not a browser-related issue, what do you see when you use inspect element on the missing / broken images? Can you make a screenshot of that, and add it to your question?